# Button click not switching activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I've been trying to get this app to switch activities by simply clicking the button, but the app simply refreshes and I stay on the same activity. Nothing happens. And if I uncomment the lines of code for my second activity, the OnClick ones, I get null pointer errors. I have no idea what I could be doing wrong. Here's my code in main activity:

```
package com.example.commontaskslite;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private TimePicker alarmClock;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private AlarmManager alarmManager;
    private Button search;
    private Button redial;
    private Button address;
    boolean checked = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        alarmClock = (TimePicker) findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
        alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);

        search = (Button) findViewById(R.id.search);
        redial = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redial);
        address = (Button) findViewById(R.id.address);

        search.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openSearch(view);
            }
        });

        redial.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openRedial(view);
            }
        });

        address.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openShowAddress(view);
            }
        });

        toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener(){
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked){
                if(isChecked){
                    checked = true;
                    onToggleClicked();
                }
                else{
                    checked = false;
                    onToggleClicked();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void openSearch(View V){
        Intent _intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Search.class);
        startActivity(_intent);
    }

    public void openRedial(View V){
        Intent _intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Redial.class);
        startActivity(_intent);
    }

    public void openShowAddress(View V){
        Intent _intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,ShowAddress.class);
        startActivity(_intent);
    }

    public void onToggleClicked(){
        long time;
        if(checked) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "ALARM ON", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, alarmClock.getHour());
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, alarmClock.getMinute());

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);

            time = (calendar.getTimeInMillis() - (calendar.getTimeInMillis() % 60000));

            if (System.currentTimeMillis() > time) {
                if (calendar.AM_PM == 0) {
                    time = time + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 12);
                } else {
                    time = time + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
                }
            }
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time, 10000, pendingIntent);
        }
        else{
            alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"ALARM OFF", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            AlarmReceiver.ringtone.stop();
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the code in the second activity:

```
package com.example.commontaskslite;

import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.SearchView;
import android.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener;

public class Search extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private Button alarm;
    private Button redial;
    private Button address;
    private SearchView searchView;
    private String searchQuery;
    private Intent intent;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        intent = getIntent();/*
        address = (Button) findViewById(R.id.address2);
        redial = (Button) findViewById(R.id.redial2);
        alarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alarm);
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                searchQuery = s;
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });

        address.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openShowAddress(view);
            }
        });

        redial.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openRedial(view);
            }
        });

        alarm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openMainActivity(view);
            }
        });*/

    }

    public void openShowAddress(View V){
        Intent _intent = new Intent(this,ShowAddress.class);
        startActivity(_intent);
    }

    public void openRedial(View V){
        Intent _intent = new Intent(this,Redial.class);
        startActivity(_intent);
    }

    public void openMainActivity(View V){
        Intent _intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(_intent);
    }

}
```

And here's the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.commontaskslite">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.CommonTasksLite">
        <activity
            android:name=".ShowAddress"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ALL_APPS"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Redial"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Search"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver">
        </receiver>
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: I see you're setting the same content layout for both activities `R.layout.activity_main`, thus having the same layout, so are you sure you didn't change activities but for this reason you see nothing change ?

Comment: if it's the case that you forget to change the layout for Search Activity, then that's why it returns null when you ask for view that were supposed to be in the actual search layout not in the activity one, it just didn't find it in the `R.layout.activity_main` .

Comment: @OmarShawky Yes that was the case. I'm completely new to android and so I didn't even realize that. I copied and pasted for ease. Thank you!

Comment: No problem and Good luck in your Android career :D .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

summarizing the answer that was found in comments.

Change `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` to another layout other than `activity_main` in Search Activity.